# Preprocessor Macros in Xcode 7.3 for targets

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

If I create a new project in Xcode 7.3 the "Preprocessor Macros" setting only appears for the project.  It doesn't appear in the build settings for any of the targets in my project.

How do you create a preprocessor macro for a target only in a project in Xcode 7.3?

Comment: Do you have your build settings view set to Basic or Advanced? The Basic view will only show you modified properties, and in the case of a new target, you wouldn't have modified preprocessor.

Comment: That was it!  Somehow the project was set to "advanced" and the targets set to "basic".

Comment: Going to convert to an answer then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the default view in Xcode (Basic), you only see a list of settings that are changed. When you create a new scheme, you have few (or no, can't remember) changed settings, and consequently wouldn't see the Preprocessor Macros region. Change your view to Advanced, and everything should become visible.

I think you can alternatively search the name directly, and that should pull it up too. I can't remember offhand, though, and I'm not at my Mac at the moment.

Comment: It's actually (in Xcode 7) "All" that you have to click on, and it doesn't work just to search directly.  :)